# Get count of Foreign Key on a query using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on an example/learning blog project, and I have two classes in `models.py` (see below) named Post and Comment.  `Post` contains the blog post information and `Comment` contains the replies on each post.

`Models.py`

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='blogpost', lazy='dynamic')



class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    reply = db.Column(db.String(500))
    commentor = db.Column(db.String(64))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

I would like to query the `Post` class, while at the same time returning the count of the `Comment.reply` on each blog post.

My query at present on the `Post` class is as follows:

```
@app.route('/index')
def explore():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
        page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
    next_url = url_for('explore', page=posts.next_num) \
        if posts.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('explore', page=posts.prev_num) \
        if posts.has_prev else None
    return render_template("index.html", title='Explore', posts=posts.items,
                          next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

**Question:**  How do I get the count of `reply` on each `Post` using Flask and SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to handle this is once you do the query on `posts` you can use {{ posts.comments.count() }} in the template to access the related comments as this is a one-to-many relationship.